# Dojo how to get JSON attribute from dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore

Tags: json, dojo, store

I have the below JSON in the typeData variable that is then put into a dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore.  What I need to know is how to check the value of **status**, was it set to "success" or some other value.  I've not been able to figure out how to get the value of **status** from a ItemFileReadStore, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var typesData = {
        status: "success",
        label: "name",
        identifier: "value",
        items: [
            {value: 3, name: "Truck"},
            {value: 8, name: "Van"},
            {value: 6, name: "Car"},
            {value: 7, name: "Scooter"}
        ]
    };
var test = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: typesData });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ItemFileReadStore` will not handle additional attributes on the data object.  However, you can extend the `ItemFileReadStore` to do what you need.  You will be overriding 'internal' methods, so it's developer beware.

```
dojo.declare("MyCustomStore", [Store], {
    _getItemsFromLoadedData: function(/* Object */ dataObject){
        this.serverStatus = dataObject.status;                     
        this.inherited(arguments);                            
    }
});

var typesData = {
    status: "success",
    label: "name",
    identifier: "value",
    items: [
        {value: 3, name: "Truck"},
        {value: 8, name: "Van"},
        {value: 6, name: "Car"},
        {value: 7, name: "Scooter"}
    ]
};
var test = new MyCustomStore({ data: typesData });
test._forceLoad(); // forces the processing of the data object

console.debug(test.serverStatus);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/dVGSc/

Comment: Thanks Craig, I would have never figured that one out.