# dojo dijit.form.select : getting data out of the dataStore?

Tags: javascript, html, json, select, dojo

I am using dojo and want to populate a dijit.form.select widget from a dataStore (this works).
Whenever I make a selection in the select-widget, other fields from my dataStore should be read and then be displayed in the textBoxes on the page.

Unfortunately I dont know how to read the other fields from my data store. Here is my code:

http://jsbin.com/xxx

The important stuff happens if you scroll all the way down.

Here is the javascript Object which is then read into the dataStore:

```
  var jsonData = {"identifier":"name",
                  "label": "subject_main",
                  "items": [
    {"name":"departure",   "subject_main":"123",  "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"},
    {"name":"direct",       "subject_main":"456",  "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"},
    {"name":"Messaging",           "subject_main":"789",  "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"},
    {"name":"exchange",      "subject_main":"1011", "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"},
    {"name":"Zilo",                "subject_main":"1213", "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"},
    {"name":"Stub_implementation",            "subject_main":"1415", "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"},
    {"name":"Standard_implementation",  "subject_main":"1617", "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"}
                        ]};
  </script>
```

For ex when I select
"name":"Messaging",           "subject_main":"789",  "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"

Messaging should be displayed in my dijit.

EDIT: Lucian helped me a lot! Here is my final solution for the problem:

> ```
> <title>Hello Dijit!</title>
> <!-- load Dojo -->
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
> <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.1/dojo/dojo.js"
> ```
>
> data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad:
>   true">
>
> Beladeauftrag
>        Adresse
>    
>          
>           Navigation>
>
> ```
> <label for="load">Laden am</label><br>
> <input type="text" value=""
> data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
> data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" id="load" /><br>
>
> <label for="from">von</label><br>
> <input type="text" value=""
> data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
> data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" id="from" /><br>
>
> <label for="till">bis</label><br>
> <input type="text" value=""
> data-dojo-type="dijit/form/TextBox"
> data-dojo-props="trim:true, propercase:true" id="till" /><br> 
>   <script>
>     // load requirements for declarative widgets in page content
> require(["dijit/form/Button", "dojo/parser", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dojo/domReady!", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore"]);   </script>
>  <br>   <br>
>  <h2>WF auswählen</h2>   <div id="stateSelect"></div>
>    <script> 
>
>    require(["dijit/form/Select", "dojo/store/Memory",
>             "dojo/json", "dijit/registry" , "dojo/ready"],
>         function(Select, Memory, json, registry, ready) {
>
>
>
>             ready(function(){
>
>                               var jsonData = {"identifier":"name",
>               "label": "subject_main",
>               "items": [
> {"name":"Auftrag 1",   "subject_main":"123",  "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"},    {"name":"Auftrag 2",   "subject_main":"456",
> ```
>
> "subject_1":"sub1", "subject_2":"sub2"}
>                         ]};
>
> ```
>         var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: jsonData });
>
>               // code useless - nut dijit.form.select fanishes without it (??)
>
>                 // create Select widget, populating its options from the store
>                 var select = new Select({
>                     name: "WorflowSelect",
>                     store: store1,
>                     style: "width: 200px;",
>                     labelAttr: "name",
>                     maxHeight: -1, // tells _HasDropDown to fit menu within viewport
>
>                     myAttr1: "this.get(name)",
>                     myAttr2: "subject_2",
>
>
>                     onChange: function(value){
>                       // get references to widgets
>                       adressW=dijit.byId("adress");
>                       loadW=dijit.byId("load");
>                       fromW=dijit.byId("from");
>                       tillW=dijit.byId("till");
>
>                       adressW.attr("value",  "subject_main from js-object");
>                       loadW.attr("value",    "subject_1 from js-object");
>                       fromW.attr("value",    "subject_2 from js-object");                          
>
>                       tillW.attr("value", 
>                                  store1._getItemByIdentity("Auftrag 1").subject_main);
>
>                     }
>                 }, "stateSelect");
>                 select.startup();
>             });
>     }); </script> </body> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it a funny way ! Why do you define the store using a span Element ?

Take a look at this post:

[Dojo how to get JSON attribute from dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795779/dojo-how-to-get-json-attribute-from-dojo-data-itemfilereadstore)

**UPDATE:**

Thats how you should do it:

http://jsbin.com/osiniv/3/edit

Lucian

Comment: thx for the tipp! I couldn t find the documentation on how to create a data store the right way so I just copied and pasted from stackoverflow.

Now I am generating the dataStore in the script-tags and in this fasion:

var store1 = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ data: jsonData });

Still need a solution for my main problem :)

Comment: could you make a new jsfiddle ? i saw that you use getElementById to access the input elements. these elements are dijit widgets ! you shouldn't access them like that ! use myElement=dijit.byId("idHierRein"); instead ! If you want to set  the value on them do a myElement.attr("value","wertHierRein");

Comment: in production mode where is the data coming from for your form ?

Comment: In the final code the data should be stored locally in a json file and not in the code. I will make a new jsfiddle now (hope jsbin is okay, too).

You asked the question because I have a link to my dropbox in the code right? For now its okay to just have the json data hardcoded as a javascript object in the code.. no need to read external data, yet!

Comment: i ve updated my main post with a link on how to fetch & search within a itemfilereadstore...

Comment: I knot that link but I wasn t shure if that was the solution for my problem. Will try that out and mark your post as solution if this works! Huge thanks!

Btw here is my updated jsbin

http://jsbin.com/osiniv/1/edit

Comment: Your da man! Thank you ;) I would have never figured that out without an example!